# Set visible columns of UITable

Tags: jvx

I want to set the visible columns of an `UITable`. I didn't find any setVisibleColumn(s) method or similar in UITable.

Checked javadoc, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visibility is controlled by the model per UI type as I understood.

Do following:

```
book.getRowDefinition().setColumnView(ITableControl.class,
                                      new ColumnView("NAME", "NAME2"));
```

or general:

```
book.getRowDefinition().setColumnView(null, new ColumnView("NAME", "NAME2" ));
```